# Where Safari stores the info about just installed/enabled/disabled extensions?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

I need to develop a Safari native (in-application) extension for enterprise and interested to know how to silently install/update/uninstall the extension.

The 'root' access is presumed granted.

I'd like to know where Safari preserves the information about extensions? Placement, format, accessibility.

The goal is to bypass the message box requiring the end user explicitly grant the permission to run the extension.

Actual for 10.10-10.12 and for High Sierra also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions and settings (.plist) are located in the directory:

```
/Users/Username/Library/Safari/Extensions
```

The settings for the extensions are in `Extensions.plist`, which hold keys for each of the extensions that happen to be installed. A typical example would look similar to this:

```
<key>Installed Extensions</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Added Non-Default Toolbar Items</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Archive File Name</key>
        <string>AdBlock-2.safariextz</string>
        <key>Bundle Directory Name</key>
        <string>AdBlock-2.safariextension</string>
        <key>Bundle Identifier</key>
        <string>com.betafish.adblockforsafari</string>
        <key>Developer Identifier</key>
        <string>UAMUU4S2D9</string>
        <key>Enabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Hash of Content Blocker String</key>
        <integer>9102788478644569774</integer>
        <key>Hidden Bars</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Removed Default Toolbar Items</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Signature</key>
        <data>
        T+7di9jBVfGql8jF5OM...
        </data>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I created a native app with Extesnion. Safari loaded the extension in Development Mode I had to explicitly agree to enable it. Now I have the proper tool button for my extension. But the above mentioned plist has no reference to this extension (actually to any extensions)...

Comment: Can't find the directory `~/Library/Safari/Extensions` for Safari v14.0